# Bit needed to drill hole for latch?

Tags: wood, doors, drill

I recently purchased this [Kwikset 96870-100 Belleview Single Cylinder Handleset](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004EPYSFA), and I need to drill the hole for the latch.

What size bit should I buy for this job and can I buy at [everyone's favorite Prime online store](https://www.amazon.com/ref=nav_logo)?

Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you get yourself a "Door Lock Installation Kit"
[image]

With 2 different size hole saws and an adjustable jig I've found these to be reasonably fool-proof.

Comment: I have one like this and wouldn't go any other way.  Also come in super handy if you have to re-drill the larger hole in old doors where the holes were closer to the edge of the door than they are with more modern ones.

Answer (score 2):

For the latch cylinder, use a spade bit that's the same size (or slightly bigger diameter) than the cylinder. It's important to make sure you drill accurately, perpendicular to the door.

For recessing the faceplate of the latch and of the strike plate, you'll want a router to get the right depth, plus a chisel to square off the edges. (Or you can do it all with a chisel with a bit of skill. Personally I don't have that skill...)

Comment: +1 Just measure carefully and make sure you drill perpendicular to the surface of the door. A sharp chisel should be sufficient for recessing though, you'll need if for squaring off the corners even if you use a router.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BOPE56) will get you where you need to go. That type of latch needs accuracy, for a newbie, this guide will help make up for experience.